# RabbitMQ: expires-policy does not delete queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ. The problem is, the queues are not getting deleted, despite me having a policy set up for this and I cannot figure out why it is not working.

This is the policy definition:

[image: This is the queue.]

And this is a typical queue; it is idle for a long time and has 0 consumers.

[image]

I know the [rules](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl) for expiring, however I cannot see that any of this would be the case. Any hints on what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you provide `restuser*` doesn't match the name of the queue `restresult-user001n5gb2`, you can also confirm that from the Policy applied to the queue, here being ha.

Two additional points to pay attention to:

1. the pattern is a regular expression, and unless you "anchor" the beginning of the match or its end, as long as your pattern shows somewhere in the name it's good. `restuse` as a pattern should yield the same result as your pattern. If you want to match any queue starting with restuser, the pattern should be `^restuser`
2. Policies are not cumulative (if you have configured high availability through policies, and you want to keep it for your restuser queues, you'll need to add the ha parameters to your clearrestuser policy too.

Comment: Thanks so far, unfortunately I cannot get it work. I've implemented several policies based on your answer, but not one queue is is deleted:https://imgur.com/a/xwuUmYJ

Comment: @MatthiasDietl could you share the policies you've tried?

Comment: And you see the policy applied on your queue(s)? From the extract you provided, I'd expect all queues where it matches would have the policy clearrestuser applied, but it's a guess, which depends on in which order you have defined the policies and when the queue were created. Finally, have you confirmed there is no consumer on the queues?

Comment: The queue list is still growing, not one is removed, despite having confirmed 0 consumers. The queues in question were created from 2 weeks ago to today. I cannot see a difference in which order i create the queues - at least the policy with nothing but "expires=1" should work, right?

Comment: any of them should work, but indeed it's better to start from the simple case when you start debugging. Can you confirm you see the policy applied in the queue view, and that it matches one of the 3 you have provided the link to?

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I've checked the queue detail view and saw that no policy was applied. So, for testing, I've created a policy with no pattern at all - and this one works! I'm doing some further testing with the pattern to understand what's going on.

Comment: If you have enough to go on, great. If you want help with the patterns, please provide the queue names, as well as the patterns you've tried that didn't match. In any case, good luck with your investigation